# Rounded corners in bxSlider

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

I need rounded corners in bxSlider.

I have this code but with js it isn't work:

```
#slider_mid {
    width: 940px; 
    height:374px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background:#093;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this at the end of your bxSlider CSS file

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper img {
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: add this at the end of your bxSlider CSS file

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I ran into the issue as well and fixing it was simpler than you may think. The problem is BxSlider adds a z-index of 50 to its elements.

Add a higher z-index to your element with the border-radius and ta-da! 
(I add a position as well because z-index won't work on non-positioned elements.)

```
#slider_mid {
    width: 940px; 
    height:374px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-radius: 100px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background:#093;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `useCSS:true` inside of this function `$('.bxslider').bxSlider({...})` it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).